# A good reference for popular javadoc tags to use?

Tags: javadoc

I'd like to use custom tags in my javadocs, but stick to some kind of convention so other people might have an easier time making sense of them. On Oracle's official javadoc documentation page, they've listed the basic tags, which is a small set, compared to the list of tags that appear in my editor's javadoc code hinting.

Is there a good reference online, which lists popular javadoc tags?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

StackOverflow user [Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23072/uri) has provided a list of custom tags that he proposes as part of his PhD research into the effectiveness of javadocs as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398546/technical-tips-for-writing-great-javadoc/398646#398646) to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398546/technical-tips-for-writing-great-javadoc).  You could adopt those and have some confidence that you're using something that is backed by some research.

Personally, I'd just stick with the standard javadoc tags and adhere to the best practices noted in Oracle's (Sun's) [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Comment: Sadly, the question and answer pages mentioned in the first paragraph have been removed.  However, the Oracle page is still in place and appears to be current; it also links to some related pages.  For less-detailed info, the Wikipedia page on Javadoc is pretty good and lists a lot of standard tags.

Answer (score 4):

**javadoc (Java JDK 8)**: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDJGIJB

**javadoc (Java JDK 7)**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to the question, but related:

To use custom javadoc tags, you either have to use a custom doclet (which can support any tags it wants), use custom taglets with the standard doclet, or use the `-tag` command line parameter to define those tags. Otherwise you'll get a warning from javadoc (and no output for this tag).

So it only really makes sense to use custom tags when you are already collaborating with someone who uses them, and this someone will say you what javadoc options you have to use. (Or you add those options yourself).

*I don't use any nonstandard tags, the standard ones are enough for me.*

Answer (score 0):

I found out this [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2018/01/javadoc-tags.html) for examples of javadoc tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/nativelibraryapis_javadoc_tags.html) site or the [github](https://github.com/tomjoht/learnapidoc/blob/main/_docs/documenting_native_library_apis/nativelibraryapis_javadoc_tags.md) as it shows usage examples and provides some good commentary on coding practices.